# is it possible to make latexmk ouput with color

Tags: latexmk

I am using this command to compile latex document in terminal like this:

```
latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./build"
```

everything goes fine. But I still facing problem that sometimes the compile may be failed and the problem is that I can hardly found out where is going wrong from the terminal ouput. I was wonder is it possible to make the latexmk ouput more better like the error message with a red color and the warning message with the yellow color or other way to make it more easy to figure out where is going wrong. is there any improment way to make it possible?

Comment: If you only need that , piping it through `grep error --color` or something similar is an option.

Comment: I'd be tempted to use the `-halt-on-error` option instead of `-interaction=nonstopmode`.  Then the error is near the bottom of the output instead of being buried in the middle.    Another possibility is to use a utility that filters the output messages down to the important ones, so that there is much less to scan through.  I use pplatex and ppdflatex, which I have latexmk configured to run instead of directly invoking one of the *latex programs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but you will have to modify your `latexmkrc` or use an independent program to pipe the output through. The example is explained [in this blog post](https://blog.mje.nz/2019-07-23-coloured-latexmk-output/), you have two options:

1. modifying latexmkrc
2. Using bespoke solution in Python or similar to cooler outputs

## latexmkrc

```
{
    no warnings 'redefine';
    use Term::ANSIColor;
    my $old_warn_running = \&main::warn_running;
    sub color_warn_running {
        print STDERR color('green');
        $old_warn_running->(@_);
        print STDERR color('reset');
    }
    if (-t STDERR) {
        # Only use color if a terminal is attached
        *main::warn_running = \&color_warn_running;
    }
}
```

## Python-based solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Filter output of pdflatex.

Usage: filter.py <latex engine> <options> <file>
"""
import os
import subprocess
import sys

import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
colorama.init()


def main(cmd):
    # Disable pdflatex line wrap (where possible)
    env = dict(os.environ, max_print_line="1000000000")

    # Run pdflatex and filter/colour output
    pdflatex = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, env=env, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
    for line in iter(pdflatex.stdout.readline, b''):
        line = line.decode('utf8').strip()
        if line.startswith('(/') or line.startswith('(./'):
            # Start loading file
            pass
        elif line.startswith(')'):
            # Finish loading file
            pass
        elif line.startswith('!'):
            # Error
            print(Fore.RED + line + Style.RESET_ALL)
        elif line.startswith('Overfull') or \
                line.startswith('Underfull') or \
                'warning' in line.lower() or \
                'missing' in line.lower() or \
                'undefined' in line.lower():
            # Warning
            print(Fore.YELLOW + line + Style.RESET_ALL)
        else:
            print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert len(sys.argv) > 1
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

You would then add `$pdflatex = "./filter.py pdflatex %O %S";` to your `latexmkrc`.